# Set string attributes for search term Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a loop which goes through an array of strings to find a string. I have a variable "searchText" that I want to highlight with red within the string "aText".

```
    for var i = 0; i < aArray?.count; i += 1 {

        if aArray![i].rangeOfString(searchText) != nil && counter != 100{
            counter += 1  
            var aText = aArray![i]
            var bText = "Example text B"
            var results = "\(aText) \n \(bText)"

            resultText.text = (resultText.text + "\n" + results)   

    }

}
```

I have used `NSMutableAttributedString`, but it was of no use. I'm quite new with Swift and have tried a lot of methods. One of the main problems is I think is because it's in a loop and I am updating my `UITextView` multiple times.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "I have used NSMutableAttributedString but it was of no use" Then you use it wrong, because that's how you "highlight with red". Your code doesn't use any attributed string, though, so who can guess what you tried?

Comment: If I use NSMutableAttributedString, the result text only shows one result. I'm not sure if its possible to combine to attributed strings to something like resultText.attributedText = mutableStringA + mutableStringB

Answer (score 0):

```
//inside Loop

if aArray![i] == "searchText" {
     var searchString:NSString = "The Result is "+aArray![i]
     let count = aArray![i].length
     var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: searchString.description)  
     myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blackColor(), range:NSRange(location: 0, length: 14))// i calculated manually .
     myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range:NSRange(location: 14, length: searchString.length))

}
```

Comment: I get an error at let count = aArray![i].length  
and how will I now implement this to make sure my textfield shows all results and not just one?